# YouTube IFrame API - player.getCurrentTime() in Android's WebView

Tags: youtube-api

When my IFrame is displayed on a desktop browser, player.getCurrentTime() returns the correct time, ie. the time of the current frame in the video.

However, when displayed inside a WebView in Android, the initial video buffering takes longer, and the returned value corresponds to the time passed since the *beginning of the buffering*, not the playback time.

Any workaround?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this when viewing your HTML directly in Browser/Chrome on Android, or only when the HTML is loaded as part of a WebView? And which version of Android are you using?

Comment: I can't confirm or reject about tha standalone Chrome broswer, since I'm having troubles getting it to display the video. About Android, it's 4.1.2 (Galaxy S3).

Comment: Well, I'm curious as to why you can't get it to display the video in a standalone browser, as that might point to a larger problem. What URL can we use to access your web page?

Comment: It's a part of a larger project, intended to be used in A WebView; there's no public version of it yet. I can load the html files in a desktop browser, though, and observe that it behaves there correctly, as noted. I'll try loading it in a mobile browser in the upcoming days. Meanwhile, if anyone noted a similar behavior, I'll appreciate your feedback.